# NiFi ifelse expression not working as expected with boolean

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I am putting JSON values into a Postgres database, chaining InvokeHTTP, CovertJSONtoSQL, ReplaceText and PutSQL. The ReplaceText is adding an additional 'ON CONFLICT...'  clause to my SQL.

As part of the ReplaceText, I'm using one of the sql attributes of the flowfile, which as far as I can tell is being persisted as a boolean (attribute is shown as 't' or 'f' in the flowfile). I need to convert this boolean (t or f) to a string ("TRUE" or "FALSE") in order that it works in my query. My tactic was to try `ifelse()` as in

```
${sql.args.3.value:ifElse("TRUE","FALSE")}
```

That always returns "FALSE" even when the attribute value it 't'.

I've made it work by casting it to a string first:

```
${sql.args.3.value:toString():equals('t'):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE")}
```

but I'm frustrated that it doesn't seem to work as expected. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like expected behavior based on the documentation of ifelse:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#ifelse

If sql.args.3.value contained the value "true" or "false" then it would be interpreted as a boolean, such as in the example in the docs where it has:

```
${bool:ifElse('a','b')}
```

Which evaluates to 'a' when the value of bool is "true".

In your case the value of sql.args.3.value is 't' or 'f' so it needs an operation to be applied which results in "true" or "false", such as what you did with the equals('t') comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess my mistake was my assumption that sql.args.3.value was a boolean, based on the way it appears in the flowfile attribute list. The sql.args.3.type is 7. I tried and failed to find a reference for what type 7 actually is!

Comment: The SQL type is going to correspond to the JDBC type which would be something like this: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/sql/Types.java.html This doesn't really have any meaning in NiFi expression language though, its just for telling the database the type. In NiFi, all attributes are strings unless a function is applied to coerces it into a specific type. The ifelse function happens to treat the strings "true" and "false" as booleans.